# Crosswalk webview on Cordova not resizing after fullscreen

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, crosswalk

I'm using Crosswalk webview on Cordova to display a webApp made with Ember.js.

In some pages the app have iframes which open a Vimeo player, and I allow them to play in fullscreen.

When the user plays it, it enters fullscreen automatically, resizing the page to increase its height. But, if the user closes fullscreen (or when the video ends and the fullscreen closes), the page isn't resized back to the original height, and my top menu gets hidden behind the mobile status bar.

If then I navigate to another url, the page gets resized and everything is beautiful again.

My question is: is there any javascript/CSS trick I could try to get around this?

INFO: I tested this against 2 phones, one Android 4.1 and the other Android 5.0, and it only happened in the Android 5.0 one. So maybe this is a Crosswalk bug. Doesn't happen at all if I use the native webView, but I wanted to avoid switching to it.

Any help appreciated ;)

Comment: Facing something similar, but I can't even play the video and after the error message my screen is kept messed up.